# Acceder a un método dentro de otro de una misma Clase

Tags: php, poo, class

Necesito acceder al método `ctrUltimoUsuario()` desde el método `ctrCrearUsuario()`, y guardar en una variable el **valor** que me **retorna** el primer método ( `ctrUltimoUsuario()` ), para envíarselo a otro método de otra clase:

```
class ControladorUsuarios{

  static public function ctrCrearUsuario(){

   //Aquí necesito llamar al método ctrUltimoUsuario, y asignar su valor en la siguiente variable
   $variable = "Valor del método ctrUltimoUsuario()"

   $response = otraClase::otroMetodo($variable);

  }

  static public function ctrUltimoUsuario(){

      return "Último usuario";

  }

}
```

La pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo acceder al método `ctrUltimoUsuario()`, desde `ctrCrearUsuario()` sin salirme de él, y asignar ese valor en la variable: **$variable**

Answer (score 1):

Creo que debería bastar con:

- Declarar en la asignación de la `$variable` el acceso de la propia clase al método estático `ctrUltimoUsuario`
- Como este método será el invocado, es decir `ctrCrearUsuario` entonces debe incluir en el `return` a la propia variable `$variable`
- Finalmente por fuera de la clase como declaraste ambos métodos como estáticos; entonces debes accederlo de esta forma:

Código:

```
ControladorUsuarios::ctrCrearUsuario();
```

El código pudiera quedar así:

```
<?php
class ControladorUsuarios
{

    static public function ctrCrearUsuario()
    {
        $variable = ControladorUsuarios::ctrUltimoUsuario();
        return $variable;
    }

    static public function ctrUltimoUsuario()
    {
      return "Último usuario";
    }
}

echo ControladorUsuarios::ctrCrearUsuario();
```

Dando lo siguiente como resultado:

> Último usuario

Comment: Gracias bro! te agradezco bastante!

Answer (score 1):

Para acceder a métodos y variables estáticas de la misma clase, puedes usar la palabra reservada `self`

```
self::ctrUltimoUsuario();
```

https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.properties

```php
class ControladorUsuarios{

  static public function ctrCrearUsuario(){

    $variable = self::ctrUltimoUsuario();

    $response = otraClase::otroMetodo($variable);

  }

  static public function ctrUltimoUsuario(){

    return "Último usuario";

  }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Vlady